# Python Regex Match Integer After String

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex in python to match and return the integer after the string `"id":` in a text file.

The text file contains the following:

```
{"page":1,"results": [{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/ba4CpvnaxvAgff2jHiaqJrVpZJ5.jpg","id":807,"original_title":"Se7en","release_date":"1995-09-22","p
```

I need to get the `807` after the `"id"`, using a regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

subject = '{"page":1,"results": [{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/ba4CpvnaxvAgff2jHiaqJrVpZJ5.jpg","id":807,"original_title":"Se7en","release_date":"1995-09-22","p'

match = re.search('"id":([^,]+)', subject)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = "no result"
print result
```

**The Output:** 807

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, adding one simple way to ignore the first match. If you use this, remember to add something like `"id":809,"etc` to your subject so that we can ignore 807 and find 809.

```
n=1
for match in re.finditer('"id":([^,]+)', subject):
    if n==1:
        print "ignoring the first match"
    else:
        print match.group(1)
    n+=1
```

Comment: works perfectly. how would i make it find the 2nd instance onward and ignore the first instance?

Comment: @user3552978 One way is to iterate through the matches: `for match in re.finditer('"id":([^,]+)', subject):` then disregard the first one.

Comment: thanks. i'm having some issues in finding how to ignore the first instance. i have the following and it works fine, but returns everything including the first instance:

Comment: f = open('temp.txt', 'r')
subject = f.read()

for match in re.finditer('"id":([^,]+)', subject):
    print match.group(1)

f.close()

Comment: @user3552978 I'm going to add that bit of code to the answer so it formats properly. By the way, I see you're recent on the site, so in case you are not aware of this, if you find someone's answer useful, you can upvote it. You can even upvote several answers in one question. Of course you're under no obligation to do so.

Comment: thanks again. it works but i'm having issues saving my output to a file, i can't seem to get it to return each value on a new line. `code`    n=1
    for match in re.finditer('"id":([^,]+)', lnkid1):
        if n==1:
            pass
        else:
            print match.group(1)
            dbfile.write(match.group(1))
        n+=1 `code`

Comment: @user3552978 You might want to ask another question, it's getting too cramped. And I'm sitting down for dinner. Wishing you a relaxing weekend.

Comment: Will do. Btw, i can't upvote yet since i'm still a noob with 0 reputation :|

Comment: @user3552978 Nice talking to you, I really got to hang up, people are waiting for me for dinner! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is more to the file than that:

```
import json

with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    print(data['results'][0]['id'])
```

If the file is *not* valid JSON, then you can get the value of `id` with:

```
from re import compile, IGNORECASE

r = compile(r'"id"\s*:\s*(\d+)', IGNORECASE)

with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for match in r.findall(f.read()):
        print(match(1))
```